# Phase Invterter Circuit

Tags: amplifier

I am using a current to voltage converter (I-V) to convert the current in the form of sine waves from an electrochemical cell (working electrode) into a voltage. I am using op-amp TLE2062 from Texas Instruments to create the I-V converter. At the output of the I-V converter the sine waves are 180 out of phase with respect to the input signal. Can anyone help me with a phase inverter circuit so that the input and output are not 180 out of phase. [image: Figure showing input signal (red) and output response (blue) from I-V converter]

Comment: Isn't it just an inverting unity amp?

Comment: Yes, Its working. Thank you. I tried it yesterday but it wouldn't work. Its great and its working fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the classical IV converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f66W2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where:

$$V_u = -I_{in}R_1$$

that's why your waveform is inverted. There are a couple of ways to circumvent that.

You can add an inverting unity gain amplifier after your current stage, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTJxV2.png)</sup>

Now:

$$
V_u = R_1 I_{in}
$$

If you want to use a single op amp there is another possibility. Please note that this second circuit could not work with your setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foFZNj.png)</sup>

Now:
$$V_u = R_1 I_{in}$$

The (big) problem with the last circuit is that your current will see a varying voltage so your sensor must be capable to provide it. For example, if you have \$I_{in}=1mA\$ and you choose \$R_1=1k\Omega\$ the voltage at the positive input of the opamp will be 1V. This might or might not be ok for your sensor depending on how it's made. The first two schematics given instead keep the voltage seen by the sensor (very) near to the reference tied to the non inverting input of the op amp, being nicer to the sensor output circuitry.